# Walk all results using a Spring Data and pagination

Tags: spring, spring-data

I'm calling a paginate service
I can walk all the paginated collection using code like this:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0,100);
Page<Event> events = eventsService.getEventsPage(pageable);
while(!events.isLast()) {
    doStuff(events)
    events = eventsService.getEventsPage(events.nextPageable())
}
doStuff(events) // rest of events
```

is there a more elegant solution?. I need the pagination because otherwise, the system will run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like having to state the service call and `doStuff` twice is somehow fragile. You can utilze the fact that `nextPageable()` will give you the `unpaged` singleton if the current page is the last one already.

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0,100);
do {
    Page<Event> events = eventsService.getEventsPage(pageable);
    doStuff(events)
    pageable = events.nextPageable();
} while(pageable.isPaged())
```

Here is the doc of `nextPageable()`.

```
 /**
 * Returns the {@link Pageable} to request the next {@link Slice}. Can be {@link Pageable#unpaged()} in case the
 * current {@link Slice} is already the last one. Clients should check {@link #hasNext()} before calling this method.
 *
 * @return
 * @see #nextOrLastPageable()
 */
Pageable nextPageable();
```

`Pageable#unpaged()` will return a singleton that returns `false` for `isPaged()`.